# create a df of mean ± std by column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen some solutions in the internet but no one seems comprehensive enough for this seemingly simple task.

Suppuse I have a df:

```
data = {'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
        'value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'value2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'value3': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a new df: the columns would be the values of the "group" coulmn, and the values would be the mean ± std for each column from the original df.

Desired output:

```
     variable     A            B
     value1   30.00±26.46  40.00±15.59
     value2     3.00±2.16    4.33±1.25
     value3     0.15±0.19    0.40±0.12
```

Comment: Can you explain how do you compute the *mean/std* ? e.g, why the pair `value3/A` has `0.15±0.19` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way :

```
out = (df.groupby("group").agg(["mean", "std"]).stack(0).round(2).astype(str)
             .agg("±".join, axis=1).unstack(0).rename_axis(columns="variable"))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

variable           A          B
value1    30.0±26.46  40.0±10.0
value2      3.0±2.65    4.0±1.0
value3      0.3±0.26    0.4±0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index='group', values=['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    aggfunc=lambda x: f'{x.mean().round(2)}±{x.std().round(2)}').T
```

Output:

```
group            A          B
value1  30.0±26.46  40.0±10.0
value2    3.0±2.65    4.0±1.0
value3    0.3±0.26    0.4±0.1
```

Comment: You should make it a string directly in your lambda

Comment: Done, @mozway. Thanks for having commented my solution!